# Let it happen, you'll cure it or forget it once

Tags: sentence-request

When someone is dealing with a big difficulty, there is a proverb in my language which says: "die or cure". It means if there is a way to solve the problem then do it in any possible way, and if not forget about it and then don't worry about it anymore.
Example:

> **Person B)** What's wrong with you George?
>
> **Person A)** Nothing! Just Kate is going to come to my work and make me lose face. She is going to tell all the story to the boss. I asked her not to do that, but she didn't agree and threatened me to come today. I'm really worried what will happen when the boss hears these all.
>
> **Person B)** Don't worry man! Let it happen .......[the proverb].......

Is there any equivalent for this proverb in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let the chips fall where they may.** To allow events to unfold naturally; to accept what occurs without prejudice, worry, or regret.

[Link to idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+the+chips+fall+where+they+may)

However, Person A seems worried. So I am not sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sounds good, but too close to the idiom "Come what may"! Am I right @Willow Rex? <wink>

Comment: You're on the right track, but it is not the same. "Come what may" means *no matter* what happens. "let the chips fall" accounts for   *accepting* what happens. They are similar though. Stangdon's answer was better than mine is.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an idiom with exactly the same meaning, but one that occurs to me is
**[roll with the punches](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/roll+with+the+punches)** meaning "to adjust to difficult events as they happen" or "to be able to deal well with difficulties or criticism".  It's a metaphor for boxing, where a boxer should move or step back in order to gracefully absorb the force of a punch.

Comment: I like this one, and I think it fits with the 'worried' part of the question.

Comment: @A-friend  No offense meant but I think Stangdon's answer is closer IF 'worried' is an important part of the question. I love the rep points but this  was a better choice based on your question.